# VBA How do I place HTML in an email that sends through an Access module

Tags: vba, email, excel, ms-access

I have some VBA code that has been given to me that sends an email with an attachment through MS Access:

```
Sub Email_Send()


Dim strTo As String
Dim strCc As String
Dim strFrom As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strMessage As String
Dim intNrAttch As Integer
Dim strAttachments As String
Dim strAttachments2 As String
Dim Contact_Name As String
Dim EMAIL_Address As String
Dim CC_Address As String
Dim Column1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnnDB As ADODB.Connection
Dim Area As String
Dim Connection As String
Dim BasePath As String
Dim Region As String
Dim Column2 As String
Dim UPC As String
Dim Name As String
Dim FirstName As String
Dim Title As String
Dim Surname As String
Dim Bold As String
Dim a As String

BasePath = "MY PATH"

Set cnnDB = New ADODB.Connection
With cnnDB
.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
.ConnectionString = "MY CONNECTION STRING"
.Open
End With

Set rstRst = New ADODB.Recordset
rstRst .Source = "SELECT [column1], [column2], [column3]" & _
        "FROM table1"

    rstRst.Open , cnnDB
    rstRst.MoveFirst


    Do While Not rstRst .EOF
        Column1 = rstRst.Fields("Column1")
        Column2 = rstRst.Fields("Column2")
        Column3_Address = rstRst.Fields("Column3")


        Dim Greeting As String
        If Time >= #12:00:00 PM# Then
            Greeting = "Afternoon,"
        Else
            Greeting = "Morning,"
        End If

        Dim CurrentMonth As String
        CurrentMonth = MonthName(Month(Date))

        strMessage = "Good" & Greeting & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & "...TEXT..." & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & "...TEXT..." & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & "" & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & "...TEXT..." & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & "" & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & "...TEXT..." & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & "" & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & "...TEXT..." & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & "...TEXT..." & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & "...TEXT..." & Chr(13)
        strMessage = strMessage & "...TEXT..." & Chr(13)

        strTo = EMAIL_Address
        'strCc = CC_Address
        strSubject = "Information: ...TEXT..." & Column2 & "...TEXT..."
        intNrAttch = 1

            strAttachments = BasePath & Column1 & "file.xls"

        Call SendMessageTo(strTo, strSubject, strMessage, intNrAttch,     strAttachments)

        rstRST.MoveNext
    Loop

MsgBox "sent"

NowExit:

End Sub

Public Function SendMessageTo(strTo As String, strSubject As String,     strMessage As String, intNrAttch As Integer, strAttachments As String) As     Boolean

Const Nr = 9
Dim MyOutlook As Object
Dim MyMessage As Object
Dim objNameSpace
Dim strFiles(Nr) As String
Dim strPromt As String
Dim i As Integer, intLen As Integer
Dim intStart, intPos As Integer


On Error GoTo Error_Handler

SendMessageTo = False
Set MyOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MyMessage = MyOutlook.CreateItem(0)

If strTo = "" Then
    strPromt = "You need to specify the e-mail address to wich you want to send this e-mail"
    MsgBox strPromt, vbInformation, "Send Message To... ?"
    Exit Function
End If

If intNrAttch > Nr + 1 Then
    strPromt = "You can only add up to " & Nr + 1 & " attachments. If you want     to add more you will need to change the array size"
    MsgBox strPromt, vbCritical, "Number of Attachments"
End If

intStart = 1
intLen = 0
If strAttachments <> "" Then
    For i = 0 To intNrAttch - 1
        If i < intNrAttch - 1 Then
            intLen = InStr(intStart, strAttachments, ";") - intStart + 1
            strFiles(i) = Trim(Mid(strAttachments, intStart, intLen - 1))
            intStart = intStart + intLen
    Else
            strFiles(i) = Trim(Mid(strAttachments, intStart,             Len(strAttachments) - intStart + 1))
    End If
    Next i
End If

intPos = Len(strMessage) + 1
With MyMessage
.To = strTo
.Subject = strSubject
.Body = strMessage
   strAttachments = "1"
    If     strAttachments <> "" Then
    For i = 0 To intNrAttch - 1
        .Attachments.Add strFiles(i), 1, intPos
    Next i
End If
.Send
End With


Set MyMessage = Nothing
Set MyOutlook = Nothing
SendMessageTo = True

Error_Handler_Exit:
Exit Function

Error_Handler:
MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description, vbCritical, Error
Resume Error_Handler_Exit

End Function
```

What I want to do is use HTML to format the `strMessage = "...TEXT..."` for example to put it in bold.

I have tried doing the following:

```
Set MyMessage = MyOutlook.CreateItem(0)
With MyMessage
   .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><B>WEEKLY REPPORT:</B><br>" _
            & "<img src='cid:DashboardFile.jpg'" & "width='814' height='33'><br>" _
            & "<br>Best Regards,<br>Ed</font></span>"
End With
```

I have looked at various websites, including: http://vba-useful.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/send-html-email-with-embedded-images.html But I cannot get it to work.

How can I do this?

Comment: There's no space bewteen the src and width properties when it's concatenated at runtime so you should add one.  Also, you'll still need to attach the image to the email, looks like you delete that part in your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't mix .Body and .HTMLBody. Pick one. As you want formatting & a pic, .HTMLBody is what you need.

Second: don't mix upper case and lower case HTML tags. Use lower.

Third: watch out for invalid HTML, like closing a font and a span tag that have never been opened. Also use `<br />` instead of `<br>` (outdated).

Fourth: Set the HTMLBody entirely, do not append to it.

I don't know whether your img will display but that's step two anyway.
That being said, try this:

```
MyMessage.HTMLBody = "<p class=MsoNormal>" & strMessage & "<br /><b>WEEKLY REPORT:</b><br />" _
            & "<img src='cid:DashboardFile.jpg' width='814' height='33' /><br />" _
            & "<br />Best Regards,<br />Ed</p>"
```

Edit: if you wish to keep the line breaks in strMessage, just replace `chr(13)` with `<br />` first.